# Permission denied when running `mkdir` inside of a Docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am using Docker Compose to run several containers, including one with a Postgres image. I am attempting to add a volume to that container to persist my data across container builds. However, I am receiving an error when it tries to create a directory for this volume within the container.

I run:

`docker-compose build`

then

`docker-compose up`

And I receive the following error:

ERROR: for cxbenchmark_db_1  Cannot start service db: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:368: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:57: mounting \\"/var/lib/docker/volumes/69845a017b4465e9122852a75ca194db473df95fa218658b8a60fb56eba9be9e/_data\\" to rootfs \\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/627956d63fb0480448079577a83b0b54f83866fdf31136b7c669541c3f672355/merged\\" at \\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/627956d63fb0480448079577a83b0b54f83866fdf31136b7c669541c3f672355/merged/var/lib/postgresql/data\\" caused \\"mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/627956d63fb0480448079577a83b0b54f83866fdf31136b7c669541c3f672355/merged/var/lib/postgresql/data: permission denied\\"\""

My full `docker-compose.yml` looks like this (note the service called `db` where the volume is defined):

```
version: '3'  

services:  
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:8000
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./src/static:/static
    depends_on:
      - web

  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && gunicorn cx_benchmark.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - ./src/static:/static
    expose:
      - 8000

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - /private/var/lib/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

Any ideas for how to solve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error you are seeing is not a problem (necessarily) with the explicit volume bind mount in your `compose` file, but rather with the `VOLUME` declaration in the main [`postgres` official Docker image `Dockerfile`](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/3b022607bec233463a3d055731fb710837978747/10/Dockerfile#L126):

`VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data`

Since you haven't provided a mount-point for this directory (but rather the parent), the docker engine is creating a local volume and then trying to mount that volume into your already bind-mounted location and getting a permissions error.

For clarity, here is the volume the docker engine created for you:

```
/var/lib/docker/volumes/69845a017b4465e9122852a75ca194db473df95fa218658b8a60fb56eba9be9e/_data
```

And here is the directory location at which it is trying to bind mount that dir; on top of your bind mount from `/private/var/lib/postgresql`:

```
mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/627956d63fb0480448079577a83b0b54f83866fdf31136b7c669541c3f672355/merged/var/lib/postgresql/data: permission denied
```

Now, I think the reason this is failing is that you may have turned on user namespaces in your Docker engine ("`userns-remap`" flag/setting) such that the container doesn't have permissions to create a directory in that root-owned location on your host. Barring that, the only other option is that the `postgres` container is starting as a non-root user, but I don't see anything in your compose file or the official `Dockerfile` for the latest release that uses the `USER` directive.

As an aside, since you are ending up with double-volumes because your bind mount doesn't match the `VOLUME` specifier in the postgres `Dockerfile`, you could change your compose file to mount to `/var/lib/postgresql/data` and get around that extra volume being created. Especially if you expect your DB data to end up in `/private/var/lib/postgresql`, as it may be surprising to find it isn't there, but rather in the `/var/lib/docker/volumes/..` location.

Comment: Thank you for the insight! I definitely don't want those double volumes. I changed the volumes entry in the db service of my docker-compose file to: `/private/var/lib/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data`

But now I get the following error when the postgres container tries to change the permissions on that directory:

`db_1     | chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/postgresql/data': Operation not permitted`

Any ideas for how I can fix that?

Comment: Yes, so the entrypoint script for the official image also tries to `chown` the data directory, and that is now trying to change ownership of the host-mounted directory. This is why I'm curious if your Docker engine is running with user namespaces enabled as normally this action would work for the `root` user. However, the paths shown above in `/var/lib/docker` make me think this isn't the case. What are the permission bits on `/private/var/lib/postgresql/data` and who owns it? Is this example using "Docker for Mac"?

Comment: Thank you @PhilE. I had the exact same problem and I was struggling with it for weeks. Your solution worked perfectly. :)

Comment: Hi, I was getting the same problem, I solved in other manner, but, I can't understand all your solution. What was really your solution? change permission to user of executes docker?

Comment: @PhilE Was this resolved by anyone ?
I am stuck with the same issue. 
Can we change the docker engine user ? Changing the flag dint work for me.
I am on macOs.

Comment: Had this problem as well when selinux is enabled - you can *test* by disabling it with `setenforce 0`

Comment: I suppose this gave me a little insight, but I'm also stuck; I can't seem to find an actual solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Postgres stateful set using this command it is working and persisting data when I delete the Postgres container and re-initiate it.
under the env:

- name: PGDATA

  value: /var/lib/postgresql/data

and under the volumeMounts option:

- name: nameOfPVC

  mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data

  subPath: data

this should work fine if you are trying to work with statefulset.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).